# Asana Installation using composer

Tags: php, asana

I am trying to install the asana library through the composer.

Json:

```
"asana/asana": "^0.10.0" added to composer.json and {
            "name": "asana/asana",
            "description": "A PHP client for the Asana API",
            "type": "library",
            "keywords": ["asana", "client"],
            "homepage": "https://github.com/Asana/php-asana",
            "license": "MIT",
            "require": {
                "php": ">=5.4.0",
                "nategood/httpful": "~0.2",
                "adoy/oauth2": "^1.2.0"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "instaclick/php-code-sniffer": "dev-master",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "^9"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-0": {
                    "Asana\\": "src/"
                }
            }
        }
```

to composer.lock but getting error 'Package Asana/asana has no version defined.
'

Comment: You should not alter composer.lock manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Jeto you should not edit `composer.lock` manually. To install the library, you can follow the steps mentioned in official docs [here](https://github.com/Asana/php-asana/#composer).
Assuming that you are doing a fresh install, follow steps below:

1. Put "asana/asana" package as a dependency in your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "asana/asana": "^0.10.0"
    }
}
```

2. Now run the command `composer install`

`composer.lock` file will be automatically updated by Composer when installation succeed.

**EDIT:**

OR

As mentioned by @Jeto in comments, You can simply do this using a single command: `composer require asana/asana:^0.10.0`

Comment: This will not work if there already was a composer.lock file before adding that dependency, as `composer install` will attempt to match exactly what's inside it. Step 2 should be `composer update asana/asana`. (Also note that step 1 could have been done via a command too: `composer require asana/asana:^0.10.0`.)

Comment: @Jeto agree. Thanks for pointing out. I have updated my answer.